# MP3 fingerprint tagger

Tags: mp3, fingerprint

Does anyone know of a tool which will read mp3 audio information directly (not the tag information), generate a fingerprint of that audio information, recommend tags based on the fingerprint and retag your MP3 collection?  Last.FM released a console application which did all but retag your collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-tagging MP3s](http://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s)

Answer (score 3):

The MusicBrainz Picard tagger sounds like exactly what you are looking for. It fingerprints your music regardless of existing tags and will add the correct tags.

http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger

It's not the most intuitive tool to use, but it is very effective. I have been using it a lot lately and it successfully tagged 6000+ tracks that had incorrect metadata.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I used Picard last week and it incorrectly labeled a bunch of my files.  *shrug*

Comment: That's interesting. The biggest "mistake" I've seen it make is assigning an album that I didn't like when a track appeared on multiple albums. Really there were multiple right answers and it chose one that I wouldn't have picked. 

What sort of mistakes have you seen? Also, what percentage of files was it incorrect with? 10%, 20%, 90%?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [Tunatic](http://wildbits.com/tunatic/)

> Love that song but don't know what it
> is? Tunatic can tag it for you!
>
> Ever thought ‘what is this song?’ Let
> Tunatic hear it and you will get the
> artist's name and the song's title
> within seconds. Tunatic is the very
> first song search engine based on
> sound for your computer. All you need
> is a microphone and Internet access.

*Tunatic is freeware*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  It doesn't look like Tunatic tags your MP3s for you.