# Auto tagger like in Winamp

Tags: mp3, music, winamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-tagging MP3s](https://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s)

Could you tell me is there any tool able to auto tag mp3 files like it's done in Winamp?
By doing it Winamp's way I mean by using Gracenote CDDB.

It can give you information about the file not based on file's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard), it can additionally try to identify files based on some musical footprint and arrange a directory structure as well.