# Auto analyze audio and rename ID tags

Tags: software-rec, mp3, music, media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-tagging MP3s](https://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s)

I used several applications for iOS platforms such as: Soundhound, Shazam. They work like that: First records music from mic, then searches it over internet, and shows info about recorded music. What I need is, to rename files, (re)fill wrong or unfilled id tags based on audio analysis (not from mic) like the applications above.

Is there any application that does it on Windows platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) is a popular tool.

Answer (score 2):

[WinAmp](http://www.winamp.com) can do that, even in the free version. Right-click an audio file (or multiple selected files) in the playlist or the media library, mouse-over *Send To* and click *Auto Tagger*. It uses a mixture of audio fingerprint and existing tag/filename components to retrieve the correct tags, and uses album information as well (i.e., it might find a song on an album, but if the song is in a folder with other songs that form a compilation, then it will correctly find the compilation information.)  It produces fairly accurate tags in most cases (even useful with obscure or totally untagged files).