# How can I edit many music files in the same unique way?

Tags: windows, mp3, tags, id3

I have a lot of audio files that I want to change in different ways depending on which ones they are. Is there a way on Windows 7 or a program that can do the following?

1. Turn all lower cased files to upper cased. e.g. low key > Low Key
2. Give all the same genre.
3. Replace filename with Artist and Title. e.g. 1-trackartist-songone > Artist - Song One

Comment: Also related: http://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s/95427#95427 – you just need a proper MP3 tag editor, of which there are plenty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MP3Tag](http://mp3tag.de/en/download.html) will let you massively change genre and rename files based on tags (*Convert* menu -> *Tag - Filename*). I think this solves the letter case issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [tagscanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/), I have previously used this to retag and rename a lot of my flac music, it supports mp3 and many other audio formats.